# Is there a way to hide a new process started with python code?

Tags: python, c++

I have a python script:

```
my_script.py
=================
import os
os.system('./a.out') # or subprocess or anything that runs another program.
=================
```

And an executable (written in C/C++):

```
a.out
```

When I run `python3 my_script.py`, I see the two processes `a.out` and `python3` running:

```
993  user1     20   0 20.265g 358096 143576 S  60.1  0.3   0:01.81 python3
1056 user1     20   0    4360    664    588 R   2.0  0.0   0:00.06 a.out
```

Is there a way to encapsulate `a.out` in `python3` and display only `python3`?

Comment: Write the C++ code as a Python module.

Comment: if you start a new process it will show up. Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: I would like to wrap it up inside the main python3 program. This program acts as a scheduler and can trigger hundreds of new programs. Looking for something aesthetic!

Comment: @kindall thanks I will have a look at how to re-write the C++ code as a Python module. I was just wondering if there was something easier.

Comment: So what if it shows up in the process list? There's a ton of programs running at any one time anyway a few (or a hundred) more doesn't really matter as I see it. Not worth spending time on.

Comment: @Jesper yes I think you're right! I was too focused on my first initial thoughts as having just one apparent program for all. But it makes sense, probably not worth spending time on!